# Localizing a website

Tags: localization, geolocation

I would like to present different content on my main page, depending on the user's country of origin. For example, if I have a celebrities website, I would like to show the local celebrities on the main page.

I have the ability to show the specific content to each user (stroed it by countries in the database) but what will be the best way to detetc the user's country? I saw some old posts recommending different services but since they were old, I wonder if there is a popular tool nowadays for detecting the country origin of the user.

Joel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

apache responses contain header fields like GEOIP_COUNTRY_NAME, etc.
also: http://www.hostip.info/use.html will try to resolve ips to lat/lon,
cdyne.com offers some similar service.